# Wireless earphones mic not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, sound, microphone, ubuntu-gnome

I have wireless earphones and they are working perfectly fine. But the mic doesn't work in ubuntu.  I have checked the sound setting and it doesn't show wireless device for input and shows the same for output.
I have done research on it and tried every hack i can but nothing seems to be work.
It is a ubuntu feature or a bug? My system mic is working fine. This is not an hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by this command as there were missing multimedia extras plugins on my system.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

make sure to restart the system after this.